# Pan/Zoom views within a ReactNative FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've got a FlatList consisting of multiple cells. Each cell has an View in it which supports Pan/Zoom gestures.

The Pan/Zoom Views work great standalone, but when they're part of the FlatList, they don't. As in, they don't pan or zoom. I assume they're conflicting with the FlatList's own gesture recognizers.

My FlatList is actually showing one cell per screen, so there's an opportunity to potentially disable some of the FlatList gesture recognizers or something along those lines.

Am I over complicating things by going down that route, or is there a supported way to embed Pan/Zoom Views in FlatLists?

Comment: See react-native-image-gallery. It uses gestures inside flat list.